# How to get an active UIViewController on storyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard

Can someone tell me how to get an UIView controller that it was created before?, I am using storyboard and I have read apple documentation about the method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: but this doc says that everytime I call this method it creates a new instance of the ViewController and what I want is to use the existing one.

Im looking for a UIViewController singleton on storyboard. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` once and then save the result as a strong property somewhere for re-use then you will only be creating it once.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution like this:

1. ControllerA:

```
'    SingleController * B = [SingleController shareSingleController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:con animated:YES];'

//push ControllerB
```

2. ControllerB:

```
+(instancetype)shareSingleController
{
    static SingleController * single;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{    
        //a static instance from StoryBoard

        single = (SingleController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SingleController" bundle:nil]instantiateInitialViewController];
    });
    return single;'
}
```

You can test, its a single instance.